# Excel: How to hide hours or minutes if either is zero?

Tags: excel

Right now I have formatted my cell with:

```
h "hours" m "minutes"
```

So if my cell has `7:00`, it displays as `7 hours 0 minutes`. Is there a way to remove the hours or the minutes if these are zero? Something like `7 hours`, or `0:30` as `30 minutes`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have Excel 2007 or later versions (but apparently not Excel for Mac 2011) you can achieve this with a combination of regular formatting and conditional formatting.

Assuming data in A1 down use a regular custom format like this

`[<0.0415][m]" minutes";h "hours" m "minutes"`

That will give you the same as your previous formatting except that any value < 01:00 will display like

`30 minutes`

Now you can add a conditional formatting condition. With column A selected do this

Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format > type this formula in the box

`=MINUTE(A1)=0`

Click the "format" button and set the following number format

`h" hours"`

Now if you have 16:00 in A1 that will display as just `16 hours`

[conditional formatting rules will always supercede regular formatting]

If you are dealing with "elapsed" times rather than clock times then you might want to use [h] rather than h in all the hours formats to show hours 24+

Comment: Interesting. I like the `[<0.0415]h\:m "minutes";h "hours" m "minutes"` format, it's a shame I can't set `m "minutes"` instead of `h\:m "minutes"`. Also I'm using mac excel 2011, but I can't seem to find a way to set a number format on a conditional formatting rule.

Comment: I haven't used mac excel 2011 but I believe it should be similar to Excel 2010 - in that version when you click on the format button in conditional formatting there are 4 tabs, Number, Font, Border and Fill - the first of those allows you to set a number format

Comment: I only see Font,Border and Fill, so I guess it's not there. Oh, well.  I don't entirely understand why `[<0.0415]m "minutes"` doesn't work. Is the condition specific to the hours?

Comment: OK, I didn't know that - m doesn't work because Excel thinks that the m is months not minutes (so you always get 1) but I just realised you can use [m] and that should work because that would be specific to minutes, i.e. custom format as **[<0.0415][m]" minutes";h "hours" m "minutes"** - I'll edit my answer......

Comment: AFAIK, when Excel takes "m" for months, you can use "n" to force miNutes instead.

Comment: @iDevlop, I can't make that work, when I try to use **n** Excel won't accept it, do you have a specific context? Perhaps it depends on Regional settings, mine are UK

Comment: @barryhoudini. perhaps I am mistaken. I tried in Excel, with no success, then I tried from Excel VBA and it works: `Print format(now,"hh:nn")` returns the same as `Print format(now,"hh:mm")`. So maybe it is, as you say, regional and/or limited to VBA.

Comment: Brilliant solution!